# Serial communication in windows - ClearCommError finds no data in read buffer

Tags: c++, windows, serial-communication

I want to send data from a laptop (windows 7, processor 2.60GHz) to a desktop (windows xp, processor 3.10GHz) using serial communication (using a USB to RS232 convertor). The WriteFile function is able to send the data from the laptop (NumberOfBytesWritten is correct). But on the desktop side, ClearCommError detects no data in the read buffer.

This is the relevant code in my desktop:

```
while(1)
{
    ClearCommError(hPort,&dwErrors,&commStatus);
    if (commStatus.cbInQue != 0)
        ReadFile(hPort,&data,1,&dwBytesRead,NULL);
}
```

The if condition is never satisfied.
The baudrate and other parameters in the DCB struct are the same on both sides.

The same code works when I write and read in the same system by shorting the RX and TX pins in the RS232 connector.

Comment: forget about if. just set timeout high enough and measure the time ReadFile actually takes. if it is less then timeout you read valid data. Also some sleep will be fine ... and all should be in thread ... or check readlength but i am not shore if it is updated correctly on timeout

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Spektre. As it turns out, there was no problem with the code. My RX and TX pins were interchanged.

Comment: :) good for you ... create an answer and accept it so others know its a solved question already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion guys, there was no problem with the code. My RX and TX pins were interchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You might try reworking that loop:

```
while (1) 
{ 
    ClearCommError(hPort,&dwErrors,&commStatus); 
    if (commStatus.cbInQue != 0) break; 
    Sleep(10); 
} 
ReadFile(hPort,&data,1,&dwBytesRead,NULL);
```

The sleep will give a little time for the system to respond to more data - you may be spinning too fast.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Roger. But it does not solve the problem. The if condition is still never satisfied.

Comment: The code was fine, Roger. My RX and TX pins were interchanged.